# How to clear a list in Dart?

Tags: dart

There are two options over there to clear some list

```
List<String> foo = ['a', 'b'];
...
foo = [];
// vs
foo.clear();
```

What is the best option? And when to use these variants?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> .clear() will remove data from list with the same reference and foo = [] will have clear data with new reference

Note: .clear() is the best option

Answer (score 7):

```
var list_name = new List()
```

--- creates a list of size zero

```
list_name = [val1,val2,val3]
```

--- a list containing the specified values

```
 list_name = []
```

--- clear elements with new reference

```
  list_name.clear()
```

--- removes every element from the list, but retains the list itself and it's type cast.
--- it's best option to remove all elements of list.